Truncate history of a GPG key
When you create a GnuPG key, edit it, and list packages, it still shares hints to the past changes. How can I clear/truncate the history of a GPG key?
Consider the following gpg --list-packets output I collected from an example key

I created with an expiration day, then using gpg --edit-key
un-expired it,
added a new user ID,
revoked the old user ID, and
ran clean + minimize on it:

# off=0 ctb=99 tag=6 hlen=3 plen=525
:public key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1717677364, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 807D96A528981A8A
# off=528 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=25
:user ID packet: "John K. Doe <john.k@do.e>"
# off=555 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=590
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 807D96A528981A8A
    version 4, created 1717677864, md5len 0, sigclass 0x13
    digest algo 10, begin of digest 4d c8
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 48FB7871B2226641449A0631807D96A528981A8A)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2024-06-06)
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 03)
    hashed subpkt 11 len 4 (pref-sym-algos: 9 8 7 2)
    hashed subpkt 21 len 5 (pref-hash-algos: 10 9 8 11 2)
    hashed subpkt 22 len 3 (pref-zip-algos: 2 3 1)
    hashed subpkt 30 len 1 (features: 01)
    hashed subpkt 23 len 1 (keyserver preferences: 80)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 807D96A528981A8A)
    data: [4096 bits]
# off=1148 ctb=b4 tag=13 hlen=2 plen=20
:user ID packet: "John Doe <john@do.e>"
# off=1170 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=588
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 807D96A528981A8A
    version 4, created 1717677931, md5len 0, sigclass 0x30
    digest algo 10, begin of digest 41 86
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 48FB7871B2226641449A0631807D96A528981A8A)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2024-06-06)
    hashed subpkt 29 len 23 (revocation reason 0x20 (Name and email changed))
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 807D96A528981A8A)
    data: [4096 bits]
# off=1761 ctb=b9 tag=14 hlen=3 plen=525
:public sub key packet:
    version 4, algo 1, created 1717677364, expires 0
    pkey[0]: [4096 bits]
    pkey[1]: [17 bits]
    keyid: 7AC47A9E40AF7D44
# off=2289 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=566
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 807D96A528981A8A
    version 4, created 1717677653, md5len 0, sigclass 0x18
    digest algo 10, begin of digest 13 e4
    hashed subpkt 27 len 1 (key flags: 0C)
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 48FB7871B2226641449A0631807D96A528981A8A)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2024-06-06)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 807D96A528981A8A)
    data: [4095 bits]

Note the revocation reason 0x20 (Name and email changed), John Doe <john@do.e> (old email address), etc. snippets. I want them to be removed, if possible.

You can remove the uid entry entirely with deluid, like https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9467 . Assuming it hasn't been published somewhere - public keyservers will not delete your UIDs but combine all they ever saw

As @cpt-whale commented, deluid will remove the user ID packet and hence the associated entry. AFAIC, there are shortcuts to truncate the history. One can only individually delete entries using delkey, delsig, and deluid.

You can remove the uid entry entirely with deluid, like crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9467 . Assuming it hasn't been published somewhere - public keyservers will not delete your UIDs but combine all they ever saw

